# I want to display data in mulitpe rows when overflowed one row

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I'm new to flutter and I have problem with displaying data in multiple rows. I'm fetching users from API and displaying button for each user, users are displayed in row like this:[image]

This "Spremi" button is not in the row it is for sending data.
here is the code:  `Row( children: _dokument!.podijeljenoSa.clanovi.map((e) => OutlinedButton.icon( label: Text(e["naziv"]), icon: const Icon(Icons.check), onPressed: () async { removeMember(e.naziv);},)).toList()),`

How can I display users in new row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to scroll horizontally the you can try this

```
Wrap(  direction: Axis.horizontal,children: _dokument!.podijeljenoSa.clanovi.map((e) => OutlinedButton.icon( label: Text(e["naziv"]), icon: const Icon(Icons.check), onPressed: () async { removeMember(e.naziv);},)).toList()),
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the `Row` in a `SingleChildScrollView`... and set the `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal`

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Row( 
    children: _dokument!.podijeljenoSa.clanovi.map((e) => 
      OutlinedButton.icon( 
        label: Text(e["naziv"]), 
        icon: const Icon(Icons.check), 
        onPressed: () async { removeMember(e.naziv);},
      )
    ).toList()
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Wrap(  direction: Axis.horizontal,children: _dokument!.podijeljenoSa.clanovi.map((e) => OutlinedButton.icon( label: Text(e["naziv"]), icon: const Icon(Icons.check), onPressed: () async { removeMember(e.naziv);},)).toList()),
```